# Testing URLDownloadToFile file sizes before downloading to identify files that don't exist

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm running an excel vba to download images from a URL to a specific folder on the computer.  The vba works perfectly.

However, due to the way I'm running the vba, sometimes the image that I'm sending to download from a URL does not actually exist.  Even though the image doesn't exist, the website's URL SEO creates a blank image rather than returning an error page.

So when I send the URL to the URLDownloadToFile, I'd like to test the file size.  If it's a specific, fixed, small size...then I would know it's a blank created image rather than an actual image and not attempt downloading it.

I know I could run another macro after the download occurs to test file sizes and delete the files after downloading, but I was hoping I could somehow modify URLDownloadToFile during the download attempt rather than parsing files afterword.

```
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
  Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
  ) As Long
```

Here's an example of the blank created image it would download:
https://www.denverfoods.net/image/item/0265395?image=02

Here is the function calling the URLDownloadToFile

```
Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim lngRetVal As Long
    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If lngRetVal = 0 Then
        DownloadFile = True
    Else
        MsgBox ("Error Downloading, lngRetVal = " & lngRetVal & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "URL = " & URL & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "File = " & LocalFilename)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'd take a look at [InternetOpenUrlA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopenurla) - if you get the http headers you should be able to determine the size. That said, it's going to be a ton of work if you're just looking to avoid tiny files (I could see going through the effort to avoid *huge* files) - why not just check the size after you download them?

Comment: As @Comintern noted, make HEAD HTTP request and check headers.

Comment: Yes it does seem like a lot of work with parsing the headers.  The reason why I want to do it during the download is because even though the file sizes are rather small, the folder with the images will continue growing in quantity during every download but each download might be just 100 new images.  To do a loop through a folder of thousands of image files just to check less than 100 new files seems excessive.  I was hoping there was a shorter way to check each file size sometime during the download.  I guess I could also create an array of the new files and loop only through them.